# Matching on basis of a pair of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df1 with multiple columns. I have df2 with same set of columns. I want to get the records of df1 which aren't present in df2. I am able to perform this task as below:

```
df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
```

Now I want to the same operation, but on the combination of NAME and ID.  This means if the NAME and ID together as a pair from df1 also exists as the same pair in df2, then that whole record should not be part of my result.

How do I accomplish this task using pandas?

Comment: Create a new column by concatenating `NAME` and `ID` and use this new column the same way you used `ID` in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy.

```
df1[(~df1[['ID', 'Name']].isin(df2[['ID', 'Name']])).any(axis=1)]
```

You pass the column names that you want to compare as a list.  The interesting part is what it outputs.

Let's say `df1` equals:

```
   ID  Name
0   0     0
1   1     1
2   2     2
3   3     3
4   4     4
5   5     5
6   6     6
7   7     7
8   8     8
9   1     1
```

And `df2` equals:

```
ID  Name
0   0     0
1   1     1
2   2     2
3   3     3
4   4     4
5   5     5
6   6     6
7   7     7
8   8     8
9   1     9
```

Every `(ID, Name)` pair between `df1` and `df2` matches **except** for row 9.  The result of my answer will return:

```
   ID  Name
9   1     1
```

Which is exactly what you want.

In more detail, when you do the mask:

```
~df[['ID', 'Name']].isin(df2[['ID', 'Name']]
```

You get this:

```
      ID   Name
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4  False  False
5  False  False
6  False  False
7  False  False
8  False  False
9  False   True
```

And we want to select the row where one of those columns is true.  For this, we can add the `any(axis=1)` onto the end which creates:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9     True
```

And then when you index using this series, it will only select row 9.

Comment: Using ~df[..].all() is infinitely less awkward than (~df[..]).any()

Comment: It would not work here, as the is.in of pandas also checked for the index position. if you swap row 0 and 9 of df2, you would not have the same result --> I don;t think this is waht we want. You can check my answer below

Answer (score 3):

**I don't think that the currently accepted answer is actually correct**. It was my impression that you would like to drop a value pair in `df1` if that pair also exists in the other dataframe, **independent of the row position** that they take in the respective dataframes.

Consider the following dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ABC'), 'b': list('CDF')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ABAC'), 'b': list('CFFF')})

df1
   a  b
0  A  C
1  B  D
2  C  F

df2
   a  b
0  A  C
1  B  F
2  A  F
3  C  F
```

So you would like to drop row 0 and 2 in `df1`. However, with the above suggestion you get

```
df1.isin(df2) 
       a      b
0   True   True
1   True  False
2  False   True
```

What you can do instead is

```
compare_cols = ['a','b'] 
mask = pd.Series(list(zip(*[df1[c] for c in compare_cols]]))).isin(list(zip(*[df2[c] for c in compare_cols])))
mask
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

That is, you construct a Series of tuples from the columns you would like to compare coming from the first dataframe, and then check whether these tuples exist in the list of tuples obtained in the same way from the respective columns in the second dataframe.

Final step: `df1 = df1.loc[~mask.values]`

As pointed out by @rvrvrv in the comments, it is best to use `mask.values` instead of just `mask` in case `df1` and `mask` do not have the same index (or one uses the `df1` index in the construction of `mask`.)

Comment: This is excellent, and so important: panda's `isin()` requires identical indices too, so you might have matching value pairs between df's, but if their indices do not match it will still return `False` ! 

(Also, so much better than the answers suggesting concatenation, since two non-identical pairs could become identical when concatenated (e.g., "Word"--"Word" and "Wordw"--"ord" would both become "WordWord"))

Comment: good point @rvrvrv about the identical indices. So to be on the safe side, it is best one  does `df1 = df1.loc[~mask.values]` in case df1 is not indexed from 1 to N.

Answer (score 1):

*Isin() would not work here as it is also comparing the index.*

Let's have a look at a super powerful tool of pandas : **merge()**

If we consider the nice example given by *user3820991*, we have :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ABC'), 'b': list('CDF')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ABAC'), 'b': list('CFFF')})

df1
   a  b
0  A  C
1  B  D
2  C  F

df2
   a  b
0  A  C
1  B  F
2  A  F
3  C  F
```

The basic merge method of pandas is **the 'inner' join**. This will give you the equivalent of **isin() method** for two columns:

```
df1.merge(df2[['a','b']], how='inner')

    a   b
0   A   C
1   C   F
```

If you would like te equivalent of the **not(isin())**, then just change the merge method by **'outer' join** *(left join would work, but for the beauty of the example, you have more possibilities with the outer join)*.

This will give you all the rows in both dataframe, we only have to add the indicator=True to be able to select the one we want:

```
df1.merge(df2[['a','b']], how='outer', indicator=True)

    a   b   _merge
0   A   C   both
1   B   D   left_only
2   C   F   both
3   B   F   right_only
4   A   F   right_only
```

We want the rows that are in df1 but not in df2, so 'left_only'. In a one liner code, you have :

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a','b'], how="outer", indicator=True
              ).query('_merge=="left_only"').drop(columns='_merge')

    a   b
1   B   D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column by concatenating NAME and ID and use this new column the same way you used ID in your question:

```
df1['temp'] = df1['NAME'].astype(str)+df1['ID'].astype(str)
df2['temp'] = df2['NAME'].astype(str)+df2['ID'].astype(str)
df1[~df1['temp'].isin(df2['temp'])].drop('temp',1)
```